# margins package returning error Error in eval(model[["call"]][["data"]], env) : object '.' not found

Tags: r, lm

I'm trying to use the `margins` package to get marginal effects of a simple linear model, but it returns the error:

```
Error in eval(model[["call"]][["data"]], env) : object '.' not found
```

This data can be used to reproduce the problem:

```
forty_rows <- structure(list(wk_dist_eff_nov16 = structure(c(18, -24, -35, 
-30, 18, 18, 4, -56, -41, 31, 18, -20, 36, 18, -15, 18, 35, 18, 
18, -58, -52, -21, -47, 19, 18, 23, -38, 4, -50, -63, 31, -2, 
-27, 2, 18, 18, -8, -12, 14, 19), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    election_2016_11 = c(NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "1", NA, 
    NA, "0", "0", NA, "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", NA, 
    NA, "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", 
    NA, "1", "0", NA, NA, "0", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))

library(tidyverse)

model <- forty_rows %>% 
             filter(!is.na(election_2016_11), 
                    wk_dist_eff_nov16 %in% -36:0) %>% 
    lm(as.numeric(election_2016_11) ~ as.factor(wk_dist_eff_nov16), data = .)
```

Which returns kind of non-sensical values but that's just an artefact of how i've created a small reproducible example (sampling only 40 rows from a df of > 500k). I can then call `tidy()` on `model` object no problem, but `margins()` returns the error:

```
tidy(model)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  term                            estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>                              <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 (Intercept)                            0       NaN       NaN     NaN
2 as.factor(wk_dist_eff_nov16)-27        0       NaN       NaN     NaN
3 as.factor(wk_dist_eff_nov16)-21        0       NaN       NaN     NaN
4 as.factor(wk_dist_eff_nov16)-15        0       NaN       NaN     NaN

library(margins)
margins(model)
Error in eval(model[["call"]][["data"]], env) : object '.' not found
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here? And how I can fix it?

Comment: `margins` appears to evaluate the `call`, check `model$call`, there's the `.`.

Comment: I see. I've tried putting the df manipulation within the lm() call (e.g. `model <- lm(as.numeric(election_2016_11) ~ as.factor(wk_dist_eff_nov16), data = forty_rows %>% filter(!is.na(election_2016_11), wk_dist_eff_nov16 %in% -36:0))`), which removes the need for the `.` pass through, and then calling `margins(model)`. But it returns the same error

Comment: Yeah, then it probably finds `"forty_rows %>% filter(!is.na(election_2016_11), wk_dist_eff_nov16 %in% -36:0))"` instead of `"."` and is confused as well. See my answer.

Comment: Jay’s answer is on point but just to be clear: there’s nothing wrong with your code, this is a bug (or rather, a deficiency) in `margins`: it shouldn’t try to infer the model data via the call expression.

Answer (score 1):

`margins` internally uses some `find_data(model, parent.frame())` stuff to find the data and finds just `.` due to piping.

You may try to explicitly define the data which can be found in `model$model`.

```
library(dplyr)

model <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(foo='bar') %>%
  lm(mpg ~ hp, data=.)

margins(model)  
# Error in eval(model[["call"]][["data"]], env) : object '.' not found

margins(model, data=model$model)  
#       hp
# -0.06823
```

Works with `mtcars` but not with your example data though.

Comment: Thanks Jay. This is a helpful pointer! When I run it with my example data, I get the error `Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]`. And when I run it with my actual df (not the example I posted but the full 500k+), it returns the error `Error in seq_len(nrow(data)) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer`. Am not sure what to make of these...

Comment: @C.Robin The error comes from `margins:::dydx.factor` lines 15 and 19. I think you should file a ticket at the [author's github](https://github.com/leeper/margins/issues).

Comment: Gotcha. Will do. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the [`marginaleffects` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/), which is designed
as a “spiritual successor” to `margins`, and is actively maintained
(disclaier: I am the author):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

forty_rows <- structure(list(wk_dist_eff_nov16 = structure(c(18, -24, -35, 
-30, 18, 18, 4, -56, -41, 31, 18, -20, 36, 18, -15, 18, 35, 18, 
18, -58, -52, -21, -47, 19, 18, 23, -38, 4, -50, -63, 31, -2, 
-27, 2, 18, 18, -8, -12, 14, 19), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    election_2016_11 = c(NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", "0", "1", NA, 
    NA, "0", "0", NA, "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", NA, 
    NA, "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, "0", NA, "0", 
    NA, "1", "0", NA, NA, "0", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-40L))

model <- forty_rows %>% 
             filter(!is.na(election_2016_11), 
                    wk_dist_eff_nov16 %in% -36:0) %>% 
    lm(as.numeric(election_2016_11) ~ as.factor(wk_dist_eff_nov16), data = .)
```

```r
mfx <- marginaleffects(model)
```

As you noted, the results of this model are non-sensical, and the
coefficients zero, so `marginaleffects` does not calculate cannot
standard errors, but it doesn’t seem to error. Perhaps it will work in
your real data. If it doesn’t, feel free to file a report on Github.

Comment: Thank you so much Vincent, for your comment and `marginaleffects`! This _does_ work with my actual data. `marginaleffects::plot_cap()` is exactly what I was looking for